# Sitecore Contact Duplication Issue - Dynamics CRM Connector

Tags: sitecore-client, dynamics-crm-module

There is a strange issue that I encountered today.

If I submit a Contact using Sitecore Forms and Sync the same contact through dynamics CRM connector, I get duplicated contacts as the identifier of both of these contacts is different.

Now I need to Sync this contact created through Sitecore form back to CRM, there will be a discrepancy in data.

Can anybody Suggest how can I handle this.

Identifier for CRM contact is Dynamics.Contactid and for Sitecore form contact is subscribe.form.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Where have you got duplicated contacts? in the CRM?

Comment: it's in Sitecore. As per the this article https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/identifying-contacts.html, When the provided identifier does not correspond to an existing identified contact record – the current contact record is saved to the xDB and the identified contact record connects to the identifier. The context device session and the current interaction are assigned to the contact record and connect to the provided identifier. If the current contact record is an identified contact that is connected to another identifier, a new contact record is created.

Comment: I believe the difference in Identifiers is causing the duplication issue. Have you ever encountered this problem ? How can we handle this ?

Comment: So as far as I understood, you have a contact which is already identified with, for example, `Source = Dynamics.Contactid`, `Identifier = SomeContactid`.  Then this contact goes to a website and submits a some form and becomes as identified with `Source = subscribe.form`, `Identifier = SomeIdentifier`. Right? Is this contact already identified for a session when he submits the form?

Comment: So we can say if contact is coming from CRM: Source = Dynamics.Contactid, Identifier = ABC. Then this contact goes to a website and submits a some form and becomes as identified with Source = subscribe.form, Identifier = ABC. So these are considered as different contacts beacuse the source is different.

Comment: It seems like it is normal behavior.

Comment: Yes it is a normal behaviur that sitecore defines in the documentation but this will Break the sync between Sitecore and CRM as we need to update the infromation of a contact brought to Sitecore via CRM by using a Sitecore form. In this case two contacts are getting created with same details.

Comment: Could you implement a custom submit action for the Sitecore Forms and identify contact with the same Source and Identifier values? Also you can change the identifier which DEF use to resolve contact. Which way do you prefer?

Comment: Ya, handling it through identifying the contact of form submission.

Comment: do you need help with it?

Comment: If you have any references, happy to take a look at those. I have also started the research at my side. I am also worried about the duplicates that have already happened. How can I now merge these contacts ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96801/discussion-between-artsem-prashkovich-and-samridhi-sachdeva).